# Display Custom Field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How can I display three recent project post on the home page of my site, I'm using the Custom Field Repeater.

```
<?php if( have_rows('recent_project') ): ?>
<div class="row-full-width mb">

  <?php while( have_rows('recent_project') ): the_row();

    // vars new project
    $project_image         = get_sub_field('project_image');
    $project_title         = get_sub_field('project_title');
    $project_link          = get_sub_field('project_link');
  ?>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 box row-no-padding scrollimation scale-in fade-in">
        <a class="hoverfx-img-contra" href="<?php echo $project_link; ?>" target="_blank">
        <div class="figure">
            <?php echo $project_title; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
        <img src="<?php echo $project_image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $project_image['alt']; ?>" class="img-responsive scrollimation scale-in fade-in">
        </a>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What is the problem or error? Depending on your homepage setup you may need to specify the `$post_id` in `have_rows()`

Comment: Hey Tristan, there's no error I just want to pull three of the latest post from this and have them displayed on the home page.

Comment: So how is your homepage setup? As a static page or latest posts?

Comment: It's setup as homepage.

Comment: Where are you saving the projects? On the home page or to another post on your site?

Comment: I'm saving them on another page.